# Why is XNode in the System.XML.Linq namespace and not System.XML?

Tags: .net, xml, linq

I'm writing some code that involved XML comparison and using [XNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.aspx).

It appears that XNode (and the other XObject) are just for reading/manipulating XML.

Why is this under the Linq namespace?

Comment: I think that MS is responsible for that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the X* family of classes are part of [Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) introduced with .NET 3.5, whereas the Xml* family of classes in `System.Xml` are the original XML parsing suite from the framework.

Classes in each namespace are generally not compatible and use different patterns for traversing XML.  If you're looking to use one or the other, it's generally more advisable to use the newer framework.

Answer (score 1):

MS wrote:

> The System.Xml namespace provides standards-based support for
>   processing XML.

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> System.Xml.Linq Namespace contains the classes for LINQ to XML. LINQ
>   to XML is an in-memory XML programming interface that enables you to
>   modify XML documents efficiently and easily.
>   Using LINQ to XML, you can:
>
> - List item
> - Load XML from files or streams.
> - Serialize XML to files or streams.
> - Create XML trees from scratch using functional construction.
> - Query XML trees using LINQ queries.
> - Manipulate in-memory XML trees.
> - Validate XML trees using XSD.
> - Use a combination of these features to transform XML trees from one shape into another.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**So, `XNode` belongs to `System.XML.Linq` namespace, because represents the abstract concept of a node (element, comment, document type, processing instruction, or text node) in the XML tree.**

Comment: "XNode belongs to System.XML.Linq namespace, because represents the abstract concept of a node (element, comment, document type, processing instruction, or text node) in the XML tree." What has that got to do with Linq?

Comment: That bold summary would best be taken from the namespace documentation rather than the XNode documentation e.g. **XNode is implemented as part of LINQ to XML, to enable Linq queries: "System.Xml.Linq Namespace contains the classes for LINQ to XML".**